# stop a rotating set of objects when mouse over with javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript is used to set a set of objects to rotate, I need the rotation to stop when the mouse moves over it. I'm still new to this, I'm guessing the solution is quite easy but I just can't get it to work.
I've tried putting the whole thing in an if statement, but that seems to just destroy the code entirely I've also tried to write a couple of methods to do it but they seem to break the code too.

here's the working javascript that just rotates the objects.

```
$(window).load(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded

var InfiniteRotator =
{

    init: function()
    {
        //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
        var initialFadeIn = 1000;


        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 5000;

        //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
        var fadeTime = 2500;

        //count number of items
        var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

        //set current item
        var currentItem = 0;

        //show first item
        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                currentItem = 0;
            }else{
                currentItem++;
            }
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        }, itemInterval);
    }
};

InfiniteRotator.init();

});
```

If you need the Html then just say, anyhelp atall is greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the timer you just set, and set it back when you move the mouse away. Try this, right after the `infiniteLoop` definition:

```
$('.rotating-item').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(infiniteLoop);
}, function() {
    infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);
        if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
            currentItem = 0;
        } else {
            currentItem++;
        }
        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

    }, itemInterval);
}
```

To avoid the code repetition you could also define that repeated function before, but that's not strictly necessary.

Comment: I have replaced this section of code but it just makes all of my objects dissapear.

Comment: I didn't mean to replace it. You should add this after the whole `var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){...}, itemInterval);` part. Is that what you tried?

Comment: I have put it in the way your suggesting but it doesn't seem to work, no objects are displayed at all. but i do see the logic in your answer, perhaps only a small tweak is in order.

Comment: Well, then the HTML (or even better, a jsfiddle) could help.

Comment: One thing: I've removed the var keyword (in the 4th row of my code), it seems to work for me in a very simple situation: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ytzuS/)

Comment: right, im actually using this to bring in a series of different social stream widgets, that currently fade in and out but i need the mouse over control to make this worth putting in.